# Why isn't Bastille in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, security

Bastille is missing from the Ubuntu 14.04 universe repository.

The main question - what should I do to replace the security provided by Bastille?  There must be a reason it was removed so how do I make up for it securely?

Comment: It looks like development stalled. Only the sourceforge-based website remains online, and it is quite outdated. http://sourceforge.net/projects/bastille-linux/files/bastille-linux/3.2.1/ is the last version listed on SF, and that is 6 years old. Presumably it got too old to be used. Perhaps you could download the source and compile it yourself.

Comment: I am not sure why it was removed from the repositories, but Ubuntu uses Appramor by default for security.